# How can I fix the error of "Unknown command" in console?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

```
package com.LeGhost.main;

import java.util.Random;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Raider extends JavaPlugin{
    private JavaPlugin plugin = Raider.this;

    public void onEnable() {
        plugin.getLogger().info("Raider fully enabled!");
    }//ENABLE

public void onDisable() {
    plugin.getLogger().info("Raider disabled!");
}//DISABLE

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player || sender instanceof ConsoleCommandSender) {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("raid")) {
            plugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(), "stop YOUR SERVER JUST GOT RAIDED!!!!!!!");//stops the server... DOES WORK
        }
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("banall")) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            int playerNumber = plugin.getServer().getOnlinePlayers().length;
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            int random = new Random().nextInt(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().length);
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Player player = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[random];
            while(playerNumber > 0) {
                plugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(), "ban " + player);
            }//THIS DOES NOT WORK! It is supposed to ban all the players that are currently on the server by choosing a random player while the player count is over 0
        }
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("moop")) {
            plugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(), "op " + sender.getName());
        }//DOES NOT WORK!! It should op the sender.
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

If someone could help me with this, I would be thankful!
Another thing is that the banall thing crashes the server.
I would like to know any fixes and to know why this does not work

Console output for banall

```
[22:09:46] [Server thread/WARN]: Unexpected exception while parsing console    command "banall"
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'banall' in plugin Raider v1.0
at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:642) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:628) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:404) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:368) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:657) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:560) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
at com.LeGhost.main.Raider.onCommand(Raider.java:32) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-994b2aa]
... 8 more
```

Console output for moop

```
[22:12:59 INFO]: Unknown command. Type "/help" for help.
```

Updated code

```
package com.LeGhost.main;

import org.bukkit.BanList;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Raider extends JavaPlugin{
private JavaPlugin plugin = Raider.this;

public void onEnable() {
    plugin.getLogger().info("Raider fully enabled!");
}

public void onDisable() {
    plugin.getLogger().info("Raider disabled!");
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player || sender instanceof ConsoleCommandSender) {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("raid")) {
            plugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(), "stop " + "Hacked lel");
        }
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("banall")) {
            plugin.getServer().getOnlinePlayers();
            Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers();
            for (Player player1 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "ban " + player1.getName() + " Hacked lel");
                ((Server) plugin).getBanList(BanList.Type.NAME).addBan(player1.getName(), "Hacked lel", null, sender.getName());
                player1.kickPlayer("Hacked lel");
            }
        }
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("moop")) {
            plugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(), "op " + sender.getName());
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you post the output of the console?

Comment: yes i can if you need it

Comment: Yes, we can pinpoint the error much quicker. Include the total output

Comment: did just now. tell me now?

Comment: Yeah, you should instead make a method in that class called ban all that takes those parameters. I'll write it in a response, one second.

Comment: what about the moop command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use the collection of players returned by `getOnlinePlayers()` like an array. Instead of `length` you need to use the `size()` method to get the number of elements contained inside the collection. To get a specific player by index you could use `(Player) Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().toArray()[index]` where `index` could be your randomly generated index.

In the line `"ban " + player` you are concatenating the `String` "ban" with the object `player`. Since `player` is not a `String`, the `toString()` method will automatically be called to turn it into one. The `toString()` method for `Player` will result in the output being something like `CraftPlayer{name="Foo"}`, and will thus try to ban a player using that exact output. Instead, use the `getName()` method for players to get the *real* name of the player (in this case "Foo").

Unless for some reason you really want to use your method of choosing a random player, you could use a for loop to ban each player on the server instead. However, even with the randomization method, you still need some kind of loop. The `player` reference is never updated to reflect choosing a different player on the server. Your code chooses *one* random player, and then bans that same player over and over again as long as the server isn't empty (causing your server to probably crash if there are more than 2 players playing on it). Instead you could try updating the player variable in each iteration after the ban, by getting the amount of players again, choosing a random index and setting the new value of the player variable. It might still be better though to just use a for each loop to iterate through every player and ban them that way.

Here is an example of banning all players using a for each loop:

```
for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "ban " + player.getName());
    //Alternatively use the method below to ban players
    //Bukkit.getBanList(BanList.Type.NAME).addBan(player.getName(), "insert_reason_here", null, sender.getName());
    //player.kickPlayer("Banned by admin");
}
```

You can also put the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation outside of the entire `onCommand` method so that you don't have to write it multiple times.

I tested out your "moop" command as a player and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: umm i added the ban thing to do what you said but it still isnt working, this time the error is on line 35

Comment: Could you detail exactly what kind of changes you made by updating your code in the question? I made a few suggestions in my answer, from creating a for loop to using the `getName()` method so I'm not quite sure which change you're referring to.

Comment: after the    plugin.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender(), "ban " + player); i added player = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[random];

Comment: Please read my answer again, it explains why using `"ban" + player` won't ban the correct player. You're also still using the collection of players like an array. You can't access an element inside the collection using just the bracket notation used for arrays. You also need to recalculate the random index since you want to select a *different* player and the amount of players has most likely changed after banning the last player.

Comment: i did    player.getName(); but i did not understand the array/index thing

Comment: I can't help you out much unless you show your entire updated code again. If there is only one player on the server, it will only ban that player. Is there more than one player on your server and only one is being banned? If so then it probably has to do with the `player` variable. Do you still have the old variable in your code?